# Integration tests with Airflow

Tags: python, google-bigquery, pytest, airflow

What would be a good/recommended way of running Airflow integration tests against BigQuery?

Airflow seems to have quite a few operators designed for testing, for example `BigQueryCheckOperator`. I am struggling to find any best practices or examples that would show how to use it for integration tests.

What would be the recommended way of doing integration tests for:

- Specific tasks
- Entire DAGs

Ideally with a testing framework written in Python, since Airflow is written in Python as well, such as `pytest` or similar.

Comment: you can see dsunit (https://github.com/viant/dsunit) for various validation option,

Comment: disclaimer: I have been contributing to endly, dsunit

Comment: @Datageek what solution did you come up with? I am currently testing my dags and tasks by calling the airflow CLI test cmd (https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#test) from test cases. Probably a quite slow approach, but it works.

Comment: I link one interesting approach, however in my opinion this is more unit than integration approach because of using mocks, but still may be helpful: https://blog.godatadriven.com/testing-and-debugging-apache-airflow

Comment: @andilabs We ended up implementing a test DAG for every production DAG. It runs the DAG itself as a subDAG (on a test data) and then it runs a test task, which compares the results between the actual and the expected datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You can run test on Entire dag like that:

```
import unittest
from airflow.models import DagBag

class TestDagIntegrity(unittest.TestCase):

LOAD_SECOND_THRESHOLD = 2

def setUp(self):
    self.dagbag = DagBag()

def test_import_dags(self):
    """ Test if dags works, no fail in import
    """
    self.assertFalse(
        len(self.dagbag.import_errors),
        'DAG import failures. Errors: {}'.format(
            self.dagbag.import_errors
        )
    )

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestDagIntegrity)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

It will be test if you dags works, if no failed on import or missing variables

Comment: so, is there a way to mock configurations (run_dag.conf, hook.get_connection and Variable) and run a dag with actual data, not only importing it?